# How to enable autocomplete for a textbox when the autocomplete on form tag is off?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, autocomplete

I have the following code snippet in my master page (abc.master)

> `<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="off">`

The above master page is used for a number of user controls. On one of them i want to enable the autocomplete for one of the textbox. I just want that textbox to show the values that the user had entered in the past. Trying to do it through :

> `<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1"  Runat="server"autocomplete="on"></asp:TextBox>`

which doesnt work for me. I also tried AutoCompleteType but that also does not work. Any pointers will be appreciable.

Comment: If u want autocomplete for only one, u should turn it on for form and the one, and turn off for each other.

Comment: @Pawan Nogariya  But for doing this, i will have to edit 13-14 user controls which i do not want. This was the reason i put the autocomplete="off" in the master page so that it gets applied to all the user controls.      Isnt there a simple way through which I could just enable it for a particular text box on a user control leaving the autocomplete="off" on the master page?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6fNJB/ works fine, what's the promlem?

Comment: @mayurRathod if we enable it for that particular usercontrol page, it will enable the autocomplete for all the text boxes on that page, which is not desired. I just want autocomplete to be enabled for one textbox and for others it should be diabled (which i accomplished through form autocomplete="off")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I figured out is that it could be done only through restricting it on controls individually. If we restrict it on the page, there is no way we could enable it on a control because the page properties takes over the controls.

Answer (score 0):

Set `autocomplete` to `on` for `form`.

Then separately set `autocomplete` for controls.

```
<form id="Form1" method="post" runat="server" autocomplete="on">
   <!-- ON for this -->
   <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" autocomplete="on"></asp:TextBox>

   <!-- OFF for this -->
   <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox2" runat="server" autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

**Edit - Option 2**

There is a way using jquery

Setautocomplete of `form` and all the elements those you want to `on` then add this to you javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input:not([autocomplete])').attr("autocomplete","off");
});
```

Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/CNk62/

Comment: But for doing this, i will have to edit 13-14 user controls which i do not want. This was the reason i put the autocomplete="off" in the master page so that it gets applied to all the user controls.

Comment: Isnt there a simple way through which I could just enable it for a particular text box on a user control leaving the autocomplete="off" on the master page?

Answer (score 0):

You can only enable the autocomplete for page from where your usercontrol is call is  using below code.
`Form.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "on")`

you can put this code on page load event.

Comment: if we enable it for that particular usercontrol page, it will enable the autocomplete for all the text boxes on that page, which is not desired. I just want autocomplete to be enabled for one textbox and for others it should be diabled (which i accomplished through form autocomplete="off")